# Can I create buckets in ceph object storage using a command-line interface?

Tags: ceph, ceph-rgw

Is it possible to create buckets in the ceph object store via the rados gateway from a CLI? I am aware of the `radosgw-admin` tool, however, it doesn't appear to have this ability. It appears mainly to handle user management. I didn't find anything to do this with other similar tools. I want to avoid having to use the dashboard in such cases. If a CLI is not available I believe there is also a REST API, however, this would not be preferred.

Comment: There are CLI tools that support the S3 and/or Swift API's that Ceph can expose for the object storage. I'm sure such tools support the creation of buckets.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can use the `s3` AWS subcommand to work with files in s3 buckets, you need to use the `s3api` subcommand to manage the creation and deletion of buckets. I was not aware of this subcommand. For example:

```
$ aws s3api create-bucket --bucket <value>
$ aws s3api delete-bucket --bucket <value>
```

You would need to configure the user's credentials in the `$HOME/.aws` directory as usual. And you can use `radosgw-admin` to create or delete the user, for example:

```
$ radosgw-admin user create --uid=$USER_NAME --display-name=$DISPLAY_NAME
$ radosgw-admin user rm --uid=$USER_NAME
```